Seeking Advice: No Citation from a PI I Applied to Work With, Who Built on My Preprint
Last year, I applied to multiple PhD programs with limited research experience but worked hard to publish a preprint on arXiv and submitted it to a workshop before the application cycle. One of the programs I applied to had a PI whose work closely aligned with the topic of my paper, I actually even cited this PI in my preprint, but I was ultimately rejected from that program. Fortunately, I ended up at a better school, so I wasn't too disappointed. My workshop submission was also rejected, and while my work wasn't groundbreaking, it did include a substantial number of experiments and an exploration of the mathematical setup for a specific problem. The primary outcome of my work was an empirically supported hypothesis: "You can get y, only if you get x." Which was the main contribution of my paper
Fast forward to this year, I came across a new preprint, and the same PI is listed as the third author. The paper builds directly on the hypothesis from my preprint, though it extends the work significantly—introducing a new metric and proving bounds on the problem, which I hadn’t done. However, the basic problem setup in their paper is the same as what I had established, and their experiments closely mirror mine. Essentially, they reached the same conclusions I did but added solution to measure this observed issue.
Their approach seems to start from the point where my work left off, but almost working backward from the hypothesis I presented. To give an example, my hypothesis was: "You can only have y if you have x." Their work suggests: "We present z, because without z, sometimes you can only have y if you have x." It feels like they couldn’t have arrived at their starting point without first having some of the insights from my work.
The issue is that I wasn't cited or acknowledged at all. Under other circumstances, I might have let it go, assuming they had similar ideas or were working on this independently. But given that I applied to work with this PI, it's almost certain they reviewed my profile and knew about my preprint.
I'm currently a first-year student with very little leverage, and this PI is at a very prestigious institution. I feel that at the very least, my work should have been cited. I'm seeking advice on how to handle this situation. What can I do when I feel like my contributions have been overlooked, but the power dynamics are clearly not in my favor?

Have you discussed this with your advisor? And, if so, please share concisely the outcome.

I have not discussed this with my advisor. As I said, I have just started the program and have known my advisor for 1 month only. So I dont even know if this should be brought up with them.

Since you’re discussing a preprint, do you think this might be the time to engage your advisor?

Frankly, given that this PI was working in the area already, I would not rule out that they were doing the work before you even contacted them.

@JonCuster That is very true and I have not ruled out that possibility at all. Frankly it is probably the case. But the point im making is that that PI definitely knew about my work, because they had to have reviewed my profile. So given they knew that similar work was out there why not cite it?

Well, how about this: PI is working in the area. Grad student of theirs is working several topics. You apply to the department. PI, who may or not be on the admissions committee, but if on the committee may or not read your application or look at your arXiv submission. Six months later their grad student brings them the paper to polish up and submit. What are the odds that the PI remembers anything about you or your arXiv submission?

There's also the possibility that you were motivated to study the question because you saw something in a paper of theirs and that, as a consequence, you've been doing things in parallel to things they've been doing for a long time. It wouldn't be strange in that case that you formulated the problem the way you did because you were inspired by the way they had been thinking about it.

It is of course possible that the PI violated your priority.
But from what you tell us, it is hard to come to this conclusion.
The PI is working in the field and has been thinking about it. Your contribution was judged to not warrant publication, maybe because it was not considered to be significant or because it was lacking originality. For example, what you investigated could have been common knowledge in the field that nobody had put into written form. This sometimes happens. Second, it is possible that all the worth of the PI's paper is in the added material. For example, some conjectures are easy to make, but finding evidence for them is very difficult. Third, assuming for a moment that the paper got its idea from you, the PI is not the primary author, which makes it more likely that the ideas from your contribution that you see copied did not come through the PI but that the PI acted in an advisory or auxiliary role. In this case, the primary author(s) might have seen your ArXiv paper and it triggered an investigation.
The only reasonable way for you to ascertain whether you were wronged is to have someone else familiar with the field look at it. This is the first and most important step.
Second, if indeed you were wronged, you need to decide what to do. You could complain to the PI's institution, who then might set up a committee to investigate and, if the evidence is good enough, force the PI to apologize to you. Electronic copies of their preprint would then be changed to have a citation of your work. This outcome seems to be unattractive given the amount of grief it will cause you, and it would be again imperative to seek some unbiased advice.
